# Copy entire page to a text document with find?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have found many examples of macros to copy selected pages to a new document, however, I am unable to find any examples of macros that use find and replace to locate a word, and copy the entire page containing that word to a new word document or notepad.

```
Sub PageGrabber()


 Dim doc As Word.Document, rng As Word.Range
    
    On Error GoTo ERRORHANDLER
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    Set rng = doc.Content
    


   
    Set rng = doc.Content
    With rng.Find
        .Text = "help"
        .Replacement.Text = " "
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = False
        .Forward = True
        While .Execute
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\page").Range.Copy
        Documents.Open FileName:="C:\test.docx"
        Selection.Paste
        rng.Collapse Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd
        Wend
    End With
    
     
    

ERRORHANDLER:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox Err.Number & vbCr & Err.Description, vbCritical
        Err.Clear
    Else
        MsgBox "Action Complete"
    End If
    
End Sub
```

I was attempting to use `while .execute` during the find to then grab the `ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\page").Range.Copy` object and paste it onto a seperate document, it resulted in the first page being copied and nothing else.

If anyone has a link to an example or some useful advice to get this to happen it would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
Sub PageGrabber()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim DocSrc As Document, DocTgt As Document
Set DocSrc = ActiveDocument
With DocSrc.Range
  With .Find
    .Text = "help"
    .Replacement.Text = " "
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    .Forward = True
    .Execute
  End With
  If .Find.Found = True Then
    Set DocTgt = Documents.Open(FileName:="C:\test.docx", AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False)
    DocTgt.Range.FormattedText = .Bookmarks("\page").Range.FormattedText
    DocTgt.Close True
  End If
End With
Set DocTgt = Nothing: Set DocSrc = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I get an error 5941 when running this script at line:

``Set Rng = Rng.Bookmarks("\page").Range``

Not sure why as it was finding the bookmark object originally.

Comment: Try removing the Set Rng = .Duplicate code line and the next line make it read Set Rng = DocSrc.bookmarks("\page").Range

Comment: The code works fine for me as originally posted... Nevertheless, I've simplified it.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at this, it does not want to work with my system for some reason, at the reference to ```.bookmarks``` it flags that a member of the collection does not exist, after modifying it to ```DocSrc.bookmarks``` I get the first page of the document returned, From what I've read pages are really hard to deal with in macros, it might just be one of those dodgy things.

Comment: That suggests you're not using the code exactly as posted. Furthermore, I would expect DocSrc.bookmarks("\page").Range to give the wrong result.